# Calculating multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need help for calculate each checkbox values in independent tables.

First example table:

```
<table id="847391201">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="49.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391201);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 1</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">49.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="39.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391201);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 2</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">39.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="29.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391201);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 3</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">29.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="19.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391201);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 4</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">19.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">Total: <span id="total_847391201">0.00 $</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="button orange">Make Payment</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Second example table:

```
<table id="847391202">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="49.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391202);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 1</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">49.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="39.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391202);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 2</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">39.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="29.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391202);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 3</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">29.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="19.90" onClick="calculate(this, 847391202);"></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Option 4</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">19.90 $</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right;">Total: <span id="total_847391202">0.00 $</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="button orange">Make Payment</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var total = parseFloat(0.00);
function calculate(item, id) {
    if (item.checked) {
        total += parseFloat(item.value);
    } else {
        total -= parseFloat(item.value);
    }
    $('span[id="total_' + id + '"]').text(total.toFixed(2) + ' $');
}
//-->
```

This code working quite good but when I clicked some option on first table then I clicked another option on second table, it continue to count. I want to make this independent for each table options. I separate tables, checkboxes and total span with ID but I couldn't make this, as I want to work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."), And better if you avoid the inline-event onclick, and use `click()` event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the total value in ONE global variable. You could use an array instead:

```
var total = new Array();
function calculate(item, id) {
    if (total[id] == undefined)
        total[id] = parseFloat(0.00);
    if (item.checked)
        total[id] += parseFloat(item.value);
    else
        total[id] -= parseFloat(item.value);
    $('span[id="total_' + id + '"]').text(total[id].toFixed(2) + ' $');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two variables to be able to track two totals?

```
var totalTableA = parseFloat(0.00);
```

`var totalTableB = parseFloat(0.00);`

Then add to the relevant total based on Id:

```
function calculate(item, id) {
if (item.checked) {
    if(id = 847391202) 
    {
         totalTableA += parseFloat(item.value);
    } else {
         totalTableB += parseFloat(item.value);
    }
} else {
    if(id = 847391202) 
    {
         totalTableA -= parseFloat(item.value);
    } else {
         totalTableB -= parseFloat(item.value);
    }
}
$('span[id="total_' + id + '"]').text(totalTableA.toFixed(2) + ' $');
$('span[id="total_' + id + '"]').text(totalTableB.toFixed(2) + ' $');
```

}